# Load images depending on creation date

Tags: android, android-image

I'm searching a way to find and load images from Pictures folder depending on creation date. For example I want to load all pictures took in the last month, but I don't know their name.

I already read about **Picasso** library, but as written in the documentation, the url is required.

So instead of scan the entire folder and then check creation date, does it exist a quicker way to accomplish this task?

Thanks

Comment: For preexisting folders there should be no shortcut, as file directory entries are not sorted by creation date and there is no system call to return files with a particular range of creation date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this could work for you. You may add selection clauses to query as well, to filter files by date for example.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " ASC");
if (cursor != null) {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(0));
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: I tried to add the following condition : `MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " > " + minDate` where `minDate` is given by getTime() method applied on Date object, but minDate seems too big and then the query doesn't return any result. What could be the problem?

Comment: Your query seems to be incorrect, I tested this `Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + ">?",
                new String[] {date.toString()}, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " ASC");` and everything was fine.

Comment: it yet doesn't working. This is code for creating date:    `String string_date = "01-01-2013";SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");    date = f.parse(string_date);`

Comment: I solved the problem by passing `String.valueOf(longDate)` in selectionArgs array, after division long value by 1000, since DATE_ADDED field is in seconds

Comment: I forgot to check column by itself, nice that you managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Timestamp while storing Images

```
String currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
```

Give this as file name. This works only if you use separate activity for clicking images.